# Correct interpretation of solubility by radicals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

In case it is relevant, the following definition comes from Galois Theory by Ian Stewart.

"Let $f$ be a polynomial over a subfield $K$ of $\mathbb {C}$, and let $\sum$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $K$. We say that $f$ is soluble by radicals if there exists a field $M$ containing $\sum$ such that $M:K$ is a radical extension."

The problem with the above definition is that $f$ is a polynomial over different fields.

---

Take $f = t^5-6t+3$. It is a usual example of a polynomial that has roots not expressible in a finite number of terms consisting of rationals, arithmetic operators and $n$th roots.

If we consider $f$ to be a polynomial over $\mathbb {Q}$, then by definition, $f$ *is not* soluble by radicals. Yet if we are to consider $f$ a polynomial over $\mathbb {C}$, then we could claim that $f$ *is* soluble by radicals.

It seems that a more proper definition would be:

Let $f$ be a polynomial over a subfield $K$ of $\mathbb {C}$, and let $\sum$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $K$. We say that $f$ is soluble by radicals *in $K$* (or maybe *over $K$*) if there exists a field $M$ containing $\sum$ such that $M:K$ is a radical extension.

Meaning that the roots of $f$ can be expressed in a finite number of terms consisting of elements in $K$, arithmetic operators and $n$th roots.

---

Since it is different from what the book states, would such an interpretation of the meaning of solubility by radicals be correct?

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ but there may not be solutions *in* $\mathbb{Q}$. The first definition is saying the solution is in the extension (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$), but I don't think that's what your definition says.